# How to write haml code for corresponding javascript?

Tags: sinatra, haml

> Here is the haml that i have created out of html. But it doesn't seem to give any output. Please help me to find out the error. May be I am going somewhere wrong with the syntax or not getting what to put in the index section of haml.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'haml'

get '/' do
  haml :index
end

__END__
@@ layout
%html
  %head

%meta{:charset => "utf-8"}/
:css
  body {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }

  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }

  .x.axis path {
    display: none;
  }

  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

%body
  %script{:src => "http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"}
  :javascript
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
        .interpolate("basis")
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.ID); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.tsv("pckt_thru.tsv", function(error, data) {
      color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "ID"; }));

      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.ID = +d.ID;
      });

      var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
        return {
          name: name,
          values: data.map(function(d) {
            return {ID: d.ID, temperature: +d[name]};
          })
        };
      });

      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.ID; }));

      y.domain([
        d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
        d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); })
      ]);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "x axis")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
          .call(xAxis);

      svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "y axis")
          .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
          .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
          .attr("y", 6)
          .attr("dy", ".71em")
          .style("text-anchor", "end")
          .text("VALUES");

      var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
          .data(cities)
        .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "city");

      city.append("path")
          .attr("class", "line")
          .attr("d", function(d) { return line(d.values); })
          .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

      city.append("text")
          .datum(function(d) { return {name: d.name, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]}; })
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.ID) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")"; })
          .attr("x", 3)
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
    });
    =yield

@@ index
#header
  %h1 Graph using Sinatra
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing all the `%` signs off the beginning of elements, e.g. `html` should be `%html`. See [the tutorial](http://haml.info/tutorial.html). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the exact source and no typos.

You are missing `%` on the tags

```
%html # not html
```

Your nesting seems to be incorrect

```
%html
%meta
  %body

%html    
  %head
    %meta
  %body
```

Try running your original html/erb through http://html2haml.heroku.com. That might help you get started if you don't know HAML at all.

Comment: Sorry i missed out on %. I have updated the code, but still not working. When i run it through terminal, i just get a blank screen nothing else.

Comment: run it through terminal? are you not running it in the browser?

Comment: Also, your still nesting outside of `%html`. While i'm not completely sure if this would break rendering, it's not correct.

Comment: I mean i get a blank screen on localhost. kwon, i'm not getting what do you want to suggest..I have embedded everything inside %html